# Launch Windows Optimize application (Windows 10) from Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7

We have a legacy Delphi 7 application that launches the Windows Defrag and On-screen Keyboard applications as follows:

```
// Defragmentation application
ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar('C:\Windows\System32\dfrg.msc'), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

// On-screen keyboard
ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar('C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe'), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Both work on Windows XP but fail on Windows 10. I spotted that the defragmentation application has had a name change to `dfrgui.exe`, but updating the code does not help. The On-screen Keyboard is still called `osk.exe` on Windows 10.

Both applications can be launched manually / directly from the command line or by double-clicking them in Windows Explorer.

My suspicion is that Windows security is preventing my application from launching anything from `C:\Windows\System32`, because I can launch several other applications from `Program Files` and from `C:\Windows`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You should be using `ShellExecuteEx()` instead of `ShellExecute()`, the `Ex` version provides better error reporting. And you should be using `CreateProcess()` instead of `ShellExecute/Ex()` when running EXE files in particular.  None of this addresses your issue, it is just good programing practice to follow in general.

Comment: Hmm, turns out you [can't use `CreateProcess()` to run `osk.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116149/), though. It must be run with `ShellExecute/Ex()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delphi 7 produces only 32-bit apps, there is no option to produce 64-bit apps (that was added in XE2).

Accessing a path under `%WINDIR%\System32` from a 32-bit app running on a 64-bit system is subject to WOW64's [File 
System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx), which will silently redirect requests for the 64-bit `System32` folder to the 32-bit `SysWOW64` folder instead.

Chances are, the apps you are trying to run only exist in the 64-bit `System32` folder and not in the 32-bit `SysWOW64` folder.

To avoid redirection, you need to either:

- replace `System32` with the special `Sysnative` alias in your paths (ie `'C:\Windows\Sysnative\osk.exe'`), which only works when running under WOW64, so you have to detect that dynamically at runtime via [`IsWow64Process()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139.aspx):

  ```
  function GetSystem32Folder: string;
  var
    Folder: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
    IsWow64: BOOL;
  begin
    Result := '';
    if IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), @IsWow64) and IsWow64 then
    begin
      SetString(Result, Folder, GetWindowsDirectory(Folder, Length(Folder)));
      if Result <> '' then
        Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Result) + 'Sysnative' + PathDelim;
    end else
    begin
      SetString(Result, Folder, GetSystemDirectory(Folder, Length(Folder)));
      if Result <> '' then
        Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Result);
    end;
  end;

  function RunDefrag: Boolean;
  var
    SysFolder: string;
    Res: Integer;
  begin
    SysFolder := GetSystem32Folder;
    Res := Integer(ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar(SysFolder + 'dfrgui.exe'), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL));
    if Res = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND then
      Res := Integer(ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar(SysFolder + 'dfrg.msc'), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL));
    Result := (Res = 0);
  end;

  function RunOnScreenKeyboard: Boolean;
  begin
    Result := (ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar(GetSystem32Folder + 'osk.exe'), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL) = 0);
  end;
  ```
- temporarily disable the Redirector via [`Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743.aspx), and then re-enable it via [`Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365745.aspx) when done:

  ```
  function GetSystem32Folder: string
  var
    Folder: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  begin
    SetString(Result, Folder, GetSystemDirectory(Folder, Length(Folder)));
    if Result <> '' then
      Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Result);
  end;

  function RunDefrag: Boolean;
  var
    SysFolder: string;
    OldState: Pointer;
    Res: Integer;
  begin    
    Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(@OldState);
    try
      SysFolder := GetSystem32Folder;
      Res := Integer(ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar(SysFolder + 'dfrgui.exe'), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL));
      if Res = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND then
        Res := Integer(ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar(SysFolder + 'dfrg.msc'), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL));
      Result := Res = 0;
    finally
      Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(OldState);
    end;
  end;

  function RunOnScreenKeyboard: Boolean;
  var
    OldState: Pointer;
  begin
    Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(@OldState);
    try
      Result := (ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar(GetSystem32Folder + 'osk.exe'), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL) = 0);
    finally
      Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(OldState);
    end;
  end;
  ```

**Update**: that being said, it turns out that a 32-bit process running under WOW64 is not allowed to run `osk.exe` when UAC is enabled:

[Delphi - On Screen Keyboard (osk.exe) works on Win32 but fails on Win64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116149/)

So, you will have to create a helper 64-bit process to launch `osk.exe` on your app's behalf when it is running under WOW64.

Comment: But which Monday?

Comment: Thanks Remy, all works great. I've written a 64-bit C++ DLL that launches the on-screen keyboard which is called from Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

A small addition to Remy Lebeau's answer:

If `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` is not available in your Delphi version, and/or if you are not sure if your target platform will support this API, you could use following code sample that calls the function dynamically:

https://www.delphipraxis.net/155861-windows-7-64bit-redirection.html

```
function ChangeFSRedirection(bDisable: Boolean): Boolean;
type
     TWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection = Function(Var Wow64FsEnableRedirection: LongBool): LongBool; StdCall;
     TWow64EnableWow64FsRedirection = Function(var Wow64FsEnableRedirection: LongBool): LongBool; StdCall;
var
    hHandle: THandle;
    Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection: TWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection;
    Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection: TWow64EnableWow64FsRedirection;
    Wow64FsEnableRedirection: LongBool;
begin
  Result := false;

  try
    hHandle := GetModuleHandle('kernel32.dll');
    @Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection := GetProcAddress(hHandle, 'Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection');
    @Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection := GetProcAddress(hHandle, 'Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection');

    if bDisable then
    begin
     if (hHandle <> 0) and (@Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection <> nil) then
     begin
       Result := Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(Wow64FsEnableRedirection);
     end;
    end else
    begin
     if (hHandle <> 0) and (@Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection <> nil) then
     begin
       Result := Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection(Wow64FsEnableRedirection);
       Result := True;
     end;
    end;
  Except
  end;
end;
```